# Dynamic menu items on ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using [menus'](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#menus) component of ionic 2 to build a side menu.

It seems like I have to define all the menu in the root component's template.

But the problem is i've to fetch ***list of components*** to be shown in side menu from **REST** call once the user is logged in.

And then update my **sidemenu** items, i tried it using **EventEmitter**. I didn't get any error but side menu is not updating, it shows initially defined items.

Can Anyone explain me how can i achieve this. Thanks for any assistance.